# how to call NodeJS from apex using Evergreen function

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, event, java

Salesforce has recently announced the Evergreen serverless functions.
Information about the Evergreen can be found:

> https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/11/introducing-salesforce-evergreen.html

In the link above, there is an example of Evergreen function and how to use salesforce logics in NodeJS.

```
import { UnitOfWork, SObject } from '@salesforce/functions';
import { PDFDocument } from 'pdfkit';
import * as fs from 'fs';

module.exports = async function(event, context, logger) {
const folioPayload = event.payload;

// Creating a new Unit Of Work instance
const uow = UnitOfWork;

// Run SOQL query to fetch folio data
const query = `SELECT Id, Description__c, Amount__c, Date__c FROM Booking_LineItems__c WHERE Reservation__c =
'${folioPayload.recordId}'`;
const folioLineItems = await context.sfApi.query(query);

// Call function to generate PDF and store in external data store
// for Files Connect
const pdfFilesConnect = await generatePdf(
    folioPayload.recordId,
    folioLineItems
);

// Update the booking object
const ReservationObject = new SObject('Reservation__c');
ReservationObject.Id = folioPayload.recordId;
ReservationObject.Status__c = 'Paid and Folio created';
uow.registerModified(ReservationObject);

// Update data
uow.commit();
};

async function generatePdf(id, lineItems) {
   # generate and store folio PDF
}
```

The code above imports UnitOfWork and SObject from @salesforce/functions, uses npm library and then commits to Salesforce.

Does someone know how can I call this function from Apex or Flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blog post [Evergreen: Serverless Functions & Compute for Customer 360 Platform](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/11/introducing-salesforce-evergreen.html) you link to says:

> A limited access developer preview of Evergreen will be available with
>   the Spring ’20 release in February.

A starting point to get on that (so you can try Evergeen out) may be the sign-up link that immediately follows.

But when/if this feature will be GA (Generally Available) so you can use it in production is unknown, at least to me.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Salesforce functions are now in beta in Spring'21, but still can't find any documentation on how to use them?